# How to disable rule in tslint file "TS2322: Type 'WebSocketAction' is not assignable to type 'boolean'."

Tags: angular, tslint

Can anybody help me to unable this rule in tslint file?
I have such message:

> "TS2322: Type 'WebSocketAction' is not assignable to type 'boolean'."

```js
export class WebSocketData {

  public authorization: string;

  constructor(
    public action: WebSocketAction = null,
    public data: any = null,
    token: string = null
  ) {
    this.authorization = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null;
  }

  public isValid(): boolean {
    return this.data && this.action;
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&&` operator expects a `boolean`, but `this.action` is `WebSocketAction`, thus you get the typescript error.

You can resolve the error by using a double exclamation point `!!`:

```js
  public isValid(): boolean {
    return this.data && !!this.action;
  }
```